# Attachment Parentid population

Tags: apex, controller, controller-extension, visualforce

I have two VF Pages. Say V1 , V2 where V1 is my parent page and V2 is included in it. Here in V1 an instance of a custom object (Call) is created and in DML insert it gets into the system. In V2 section, it allows the User to upload multiple files. The parentid of those Attachment records should be the inserted Call Id. Can someone please help me how to pass the Call Id in that attachment section? My piece of code where I try to do that is as below.
Code Snippet:

```
public pagereference saveAndRedirect() {
   /* d.folderid = UserInfo.getUserId(); //this puts it in My Personal Documents of logged in
    insert d;//insert record.*/
   // d=null;
   //return null;
   try {
      insert callobj;
      result = callobj.id;
   } catch (DmlException e) {
      System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
      String s = e.getMessage();
   }
   if (s != null) {
      PageReference redirectPage = Page.MultiAttachment;
      redirectPage.setRedirect(true);
      redirectPage.getParameters().put('id', result);
      return redirectPage;
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: How have you included the attachment page in the main one?

Comment: Yes I did by include pagename="nnnn"